# Problem with dojo tree

Tags: dojo, tree, widget

I'm trying to get the dojo tree widget working. It works with a small json object, but when i try it with a large json object it goes wrong. There is no error, just the root node. Is this a normal behavior? Is there a maximum of objects you can load? My json object contains around 800 entries.

Thanks,

Ewout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no message in the FF debug console that would help you out? I don't remember any constraint on the dojo tree widget regarding the number of objects it can handle.

my first suggestion would be look at the id's of your store. make sure these id's are unique. for example try to build a itemFileReadStore from your json object and use it in the tree.  
`var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({identifier:'idfield', label:'something', data:{items:yourjsonobject}})`

good luck